# How to backup users permissions and web parts on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, backup, web-parts, user-permissions

I want to backup all the users permission and web parts on my sharepoint, so I can restore them anytime. because few weeks ago, all of user permission and web parts on my sharepoint has gone mysteriously. I've backup all the content, but not the user permissions and web parts. Can it done without using 3rd party software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use regular site collection backups? It includes permissions and web parts:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx

Alternatively you can make regular content database backups:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx
It will also contains all permissions and web parts.

Comment: is that compatible with SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Yes, but instead of Powershell (first option in my answer) you have to use stsadm utility: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to do that without custom development and I think it is better to backup all content, but it could be useful for you to turn on Audit Reports for site collection. Using this reports you can track changes in your site collection even permission changes. To configure audit look at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx). Also you can look at third party tools for audit.